# Время жизни заказа. Проблема с оплатой

Tags: алгоритм

Есть интернет магазин. 
На бронь товара дается 30 минут. 
Т.е. если через 30 минут товар не будет куплен, то заказ отменяется и товар с брони снова уходит в продажу. 
Проблема на этапе оплаты. (Используется сбербанк)
В сбербанк передается информация о жизни заказа. Т.е. если он не ввел данные карты, то оплатить не сможет и все логично. Но т.к. используется двухфакторная оплата, то на странице ввода кода из смс время жизни заказа не имеет значения. Таким образом возникает след. ситуация: Клиент кладет товар в корзину, переходит к оплате вводит данные карты, переходит на страницу ввода кода из смс и там зависает на время большее чем время жизни заказа. Разумеется заказ уже отменен на сайте, товар уже в продаже. И тут клиент решается ввести код из смс, оплата проходит, а товара у него уже нет. 
Как решить данный вопрос. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Нельзя в сбербанк отправить запрос на отмену оплаты, чтобы при попытке оплатить просроченный товар выдало ошибку "Оплата более недействительна" или что-то вроде того

Comment: Время жизни заказа у сбербанка есть. Однако время не засчитывается на странице ввода смс

Comment: Ну это вопрос к самому сбербанку. Однако, отмена оплаты не в автоматическом режиме должна быть, я почти уверен в этом. Надо только найти нужный запрос api и отменить оплату сразу как товар был просрочен